# Terraform Azurerm Log and Metric Caterogies in azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting

Tags: azure, resources, terraform, diagnostics

I have the following code to set up diagnostic settings for a VM. Terraform plan works ok and does not report any issues; however, I get the following error on apply:

Message="Category 'WorkflowRuntime' is not supported.".

I tried with AuditEvents and a couple of other categories and got the same error. Here is the code:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "u_diag_settings" {
  count                      = "${var.uCount}"
  name                       = "${var.uName}${format("%1d", count.index+1)}-diag_setting"
  target_resource_id         = "${element(azurerm_virtual_machine.ubuntu.*.id, count.index)}"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = "${data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law_id.id}"

log {
  category = "WorkflowRuntime"
  enabled = "true"

retention_policy {
  enabled = "true"
  days    = "30"
   }
}

metric {
  category = "AllMetrics"
  enabled = "true"

retention_policy {
  enabled = "true"
  days    = "30"
  }
}
```

}

The target resource ID is a VM and I like to send the logs to a log analytics workspace. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The documentation says to use this to determine the available categories: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/monitor_diagnostic_categories.html

Answer (score 0):

As the error message said, Category 'WorkflowRuntime' is not supported. You could check [supported log categories per resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-logs-schema#supported-log-categories-per-resource-type), no supported log category for VM. Also, There is a `null` output for using [Data Source: azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/monitor_diagnostic_categories.html) about VM.

Probably, you need to have version 3.0 or higher of the **Linux Diagnostic extension** installed on that VM in order to edit your diagnostic settings through the portal.

Reference: [Linux diagnostic extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-linux) and [Bootstrapping Azure VMs with Terraform](http://teknews.cloud/bootstrapping-azure-vms-with-terraform/)